# blocking browser using user agent in squid proxy

Tags: squid

I want to block browsers using their user-agent in squid proxy.Recently i am working on blocking certain browser's like chrome, Mozilla,Firefox and to allow only internet explorer in my working environment.
Is there any to do this?

Answer (score 1):

On your squid config file

```
acl rule_name browser ^user_agent_name
```

then

```
http_access deny rule_name
```

see this for user agent names [User Agents](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/CommonUserAgents)

Note ^user_agent_name is a regular expression, so the caret means match any string starting with ^user_agent_name

e.g. ^Mozilla will block most browsers

Comment: I have creatd a acl file which has all the user-agents for chrome and firefox and etc., which that i need to block when i add the following line in squid conf
"acl xxx browser /xx/xxx/xxx.acl"

when i give squid3 -k configure
i get this error
" aclParseRegexList: Invalid regular expression 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1;':"

Comment: you need to use escape characters
Something like this ^Mozilla\/4.0\\( ... etc...